# Probability proof and making sure I cannot make further simplifications to my answer

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

The question asks me to compute the probability (sums are ok) of the probability of having at least one of r cells empty with n>r balls thrown at the cells with equal likelihood of landing in any of the cells, my proposed answer is
  Let $A_{i}\subset\Omega$, for $i=1,...,r$
  be the event that cell $i$ is empty. Then, we know by inclusion exclusion,
  that the chance that at least one of these cells is empty is
  $\begin{align*}
    P(\cup_{i=1}^{r}A_{i})=&\sum_{i=1}^{r}P(A_{i})-
      \sum_{i_{1}<i_{2}}P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}})+
      \sum_{i_{1}<i_{2}<i_{3}}P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}}\cap A_{i_{3}})
      .....\\&\pm\sum_{i_{1}<....<i_{r}}
      P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}}....\cap A_{i_{r}})
  \end{align*}$

First, computing $P(A_{i})$ for any $i$ which should be the same by symmetry.
$
\begin{equation*}
  P(A_{i})=(1-\frac{1}{r})^{n}\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{r}P(A_{i})=
  r(1-\frac{1}{r})^{n}
\end{equation*}$

I get a final answer of
$\begin{equation*}
  P(\cup_{i=1}^{r}A_{i})=
  r(1-\frac{1}{r})^{n}-\sum_{i_{1}<i_{2}}P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}})+
  \sum_{i_{1}<i_{2}<i_{3}}P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}}\cap A_{i_{3}})
  .....\pm\sum_{i_{1}<....<i_{r}}
  P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}}....\cap A_{i_{r}})
\end{equation*}$

But I am not sure if I can simplify any of the intersection probabilities in the middle. There is definitely a limit to how simple I can make this, since the inclusion and exclusion expansion depends on the parity of r, at least for the sign.

edit: I have further simplified my answer to this:
$\begin{align*}
  P(\cup_{i=1}^{r}A_{i})=&r(1-\frac{1}{r})^{n}-
    {r\choose 2}(1-\frac{2}{r})^{n}+
    {r\choose 3}(1-\frac{3}{r})^{n}
    .....\\&\pm{r\choose r-1}(1-\frac{r-1}{r})^{n}
\end{align*}$

Comment: I saw stirling numbers of the second kind in a similar question on here, but they have not been introduced in class so I dont think I can use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find explicit expressions for the various intersection probabilities. For example if $i,j,k$ are distinct then $\Pr(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)=\left(\frac{r-3}{r}\right)^n$.

You can also express the probability in terms of the [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)